# Angular 6 updating outdated dependencies in package.json

Tags: angular, npm, npm-update

I'm working with the newest version of Angular (6) and I was trying to update my `package.json` dependencies.

Is it valid to use `npm update` command to update all dependencies or are there some other methods more secure and affidable?

Running npm outdated I can see that there are so many dependencies to be updated!

Can someone give to me a full explanation regarding this task?

Thanks guys, good coding :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have here all info and explanation of what npm update does and behavior!
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

But if you want to update Angular dependence:
`ng update` will updates the current application to latest versions
or `ng update --all` Whether to update all packages in package.json
More info: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/update

Comment: '--all' functionality has been removed as updating multiple packages at once is not recommended.